# Difficult cross-tab query

Tags: sql, ms-access, many-to-many, rdbms

Tied myself a bit up in knots in the development of a relatively complicated relational database.

Purpose of database is to allow managers to arrange meetings with representatives (or groups of representatives) from particular companies.

Naturally the table, outlining the details relating to arranged meetings, is of utmost importance. Unfortunately most of its information is nigh impossible for users to parse as the fields are merely returning the numerical fields of other tables.

So really what I need, to be able to create a query that will gather all this diverse information together, tied to the meeting key, and allow users to enter in all the relevant information in a form for... well arranging such appointments.

Here's the schematic (some irrelevant info is hidden)

[image: Appointment relationship diagram]

(is it my imagination or is the png unusually small?)

I was thinking of producing a very long series of SELECTS and INNER JOINS. Something like

```
SELECT Meeting.MID, Meeting.Date_dd/mm/yyyy, Meeting.Location, Contact.Cname, Contingent.Manager [...]
FROM Meeting INNER JOIN (ContactMeeting INNER JOIN (Contact INNER JOIN [...]
```

But I am concerned because the relations are not linear; ContactMeeting branches off to Contact, Group_contact, and Contingent; that INNER JOINS in this instance may not work. ContactMeetings may have either a Contact, a Group_contact, or both present (inclusive or), but will **always** have a Contingent present (which will consist of one or more managers).

Help in relation to this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered simplifying by using subforms?

Comment: In Access 2010 (which is the rdms that I'm currently using) it's difficult to use subforms without it looking ugly - and while I've bitten the bullet for other forms, I'm reluctant to use subforms in a situation where.. ugh.. at least three would be needed. Particularly since there would be no direct link between the table in the main form and subform (that is that there would be an intermediate table... like Contingent).

Comment: Subforms do not have to look ugly, and they are one of the great strengths of MS access. Set the contained form borders to dialog, get rid of the horizontal scroll and a few other bits and the subform will blend nicely into the form. I have done it often.

Comment: Will it work across far flung tables provided that there is some sort of chain of referential integrity?

Comment: The advantage of subforms is that you can set a child and master field allowing you to include only records relevant to the master record. You can have more that one child and master field, which means that the main form can include, say, a combo for dates to further limit the subform. In addition, you can use a combo when the subform is based on, for example, a join (junction) table so that an ID becomes readable by virtue of a row source based on the relevant description table.

Comment: Thanks. However, I can't see anything in the UI to set subform border to dialog. Does it have to be done through VB?

Comment: Open the form contained by the subform control in design view, from the property sheet select the format tab, about half way down you will find Border Style. It will probably be set to Sizable. Change it to thin or dialog, which ever you prefer. I generally add an open event that checks for the parent and complains if my development variable is not set.

Comment: Transparent, Solid, Dashes, Short Dashes, Dots, etc. are the only optins I can see :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For prettier subforms, you can set some form properties for the form to be contained by the subform control. You need to open the (sub) form in design view.

[image: Border style]